# Mercurial one head, two deviations

Tags: mercurial, merge, branch

I have run into an interesting situation that I do not know how to describe. So I here is a screenshot of it (note that two programmers are working here with a central repository that both synchronize with):

The image on the left is updated to the other programmer's core (which is now the head) and the image on the right is updated to my core before the merge to dev.

[image: http://d.pr/i/aorX] [image: http://d.pr/i/7d7q]

As you can see, I have one `Core` branch `#372` merging into `Dev`. The other programmer forgot to merge with my changes at `#372` (which I had already pushed to the central repository before this changes from 375 and onwards) and continued on.

So now I have a core branch that merged into dev, and is sort of left headless. The other programmer's core is now going to be the one I am going to start with. That is not an issue. What is an issue is seeing two cores and the messy tree with confusing branching.

What can I do to end up with one core branch only? Or is this *ok* to have?

Comment: Both Paul's and David's answers below do a good job of explaining how very normal things up above.  Do a little googling to understand the difference between the terms 'head' and 'topological head', and also between 'named branch' and 'anonymous branch' in the Mercurial context and you'll be fine.  Try `hg heads --topo` as compared to `hg heads`.  Don't worry about how pretty your history looks, you can always merge down to as few heads as you want/need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you can see, I have one Core branch #372 merging into Dev. The other programmer forgot to merge with my changes at #372 (which I had already pushed to the central repository before this changes from 375 and onwards) and continued on.

That's not what I see. #372 is a parent of #373 on both sides. Both graphs, if you remove #381+ and #372+, are the same. They've been drawn differently just because the parent of the current working copy is different.

Granted, it looks a little odd, but there's no issue here. After #372+ is committed, it will need to be merged with #381 (or whatever the current Core head is by then) at some point, but that's nothing exceptional.

Comment: What if I don't have any changes in 372+, should I leave it as is. And then if I have some `core` changes later on, should I start with 372+ or 381+? I want to get back to _one_ core branch again. Do I have to explicitly make some changes in 372+ just so that I can merge it with the core head? My apologies if my wording is confusing, since I am confused myself!

Comment: Ok, then it's just that you haven't updated to the latest code. `hg update Core` will update your working copy to the latest version in the `Core` branch. #372+ will cease to exist (it doesn't actually exist, it's an artefact of whatever tool you're using to draw the graphs). I think the revision you end up at will depend on how the merge in #382 was done and whether that's now the head of Core or if #381 is.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, `Core` actually has 0 *topological heads* since changesets 381 and 372 were both merged with `dev`. On your graph you see that long line extending from changeset 372 because your working directory is on that changeset right now. The line is indicating that any commits you make will be children of 372. The other programmer's working directory is on changeset 381, which is why his graph looks different. Once you update to 381 your graph will look the same as the other one.

So to answer your question, this won't be an issue since `Core`'s *branch heads* have all been merged into dev. Also if you did end up with multiple topological heads on `Core`, mercurial would warn you about it when you pulled in the new head.